# Trying to delete sharpoint file with a "#" in the name

Tags: sharepoint

A lot of the documents I’m dealing with at the moment have a “#” in the file name and when listing the files in the folder I got around this issues by doing a simple replace of the encoded value of %25

```
var fileRefOriginal = file.ServerRelativeUrl;
var fileRef = fileRefOriginal.Replace("#", "%23");
var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(sourceContext, fileRef);
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
{
  fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

But for some of the files I need to delete and I was just using this after the download;

```
sourceContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileRef).DeleteObject();
sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

but it wasn’t removing anything and didn’t give an error so I tried this which just says file not found;

```
var f = sourceContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileRef);
sourceContext.Load(f);
f.DeleteObject();
sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I’ve tried it with the original name and the converted name (using %25) but seem to be getting no where.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work, by capturing the files unique ID, then instead of using ;

`var f = sourceContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileRef);`

I used this;

`var f = sourceContext.Web.GetFileById(fileId);`

Hope it helps someone with the same issue.